# The puts() only prints the last element of the text file

Tags: c

I have a text file full of text that i want to store in the form of strings in S

```
FILE *fp;

char str[200];

char **S = malloc( 200000*sizeof( char ) );

int i=0, j;

fp = fopen("S.txt" , "r");

while( fgets (str, 200, fp)!=NULL ) 
{
    S[i] = str;
    i++;
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    puts(S[j]);

fclose(fp);
```

But the problem is that the program only prints the last string of the list. I think that maybe i allocated the memory wrong(the malloc( 200000*sizeof( char ) ) its becouse the file contains up to 1000 strings of up to 200 characters)

Comment: `S[i] = str;` only copies the address of `str` to `S[i]`,  not the contents of the _string_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
FILE *fp;

char str[200];

/* <<<ATTENTION, READ HERE>>>
 * Here, the allocation size is incorrect, one of two:
 * You should use malloc( 200000 * sizeof (char *)); as you are
 *     allocating the pointers in the array, not the space for 
 *     the strings 
 * You express (always safe) malloc( 200000 * sizeof *S ); This is
 *     a fake expression (not evaluated but to get the sizeof only)
 */
char **S = malloc( 200000 * sizeof *S );

int i=0, j;

fp = fopen("S.txt" , "r");

while( fgets (str, 200, fp)!=NULL ) 
{

    /* <<<ATTENTION, READ HERE>>>
     * the strdup(str); allocates memory (calling malloc itself)
     * and copies the contents of the string in the allocated memory.
    S[i] = strdup(str);
    i++;
}

for(j=0;j<i;j++)
    puts(S[j]);

fclose(fp);
```

With those two modifications your program will run safe (considering that you cannot allow files of more than 200000 lines of no more than 200 characters)

Your problem, not `strdup()`ing the string is that you finally made all strings point to the buffer, so the contents of the buffer after reading all the lines where the contents of the last line read.  As all pointers pointed to the same place, you got as many copies of the last line (at double space, as `fgets()` doesn't take the `\n` off the string, but `puts()` does add a `\n` after printing the string passed.

## NOTE

read [how to create a minimum, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as you can easily eliminate the error if you decide to post just a snippet of code.  Also, it makes more difficult for us to verify and check your error, or detect what is a typo from what is an error.

## NOTE2

In case you want to return all the memory allocated by your program, you can do the following:

```
for(j = 0; j < i; j++)
    free(S[j]); /* each malloc made inside strdup() */
free(S); /* the malloc you did at the beginning */
```